# How to impelment Phone call animation like iPhone's default Phone application does?

Tags: iphone, animation

My application has VOIP calling. In that I want to implement animation like iPhone's default Phone application does when User Clicks on Call button on dial Pad and animation that is done on End call button.

I have researched alot about this but haven't find anything yet. Any help will be appreciated on this topic.

Right now I have implemented scaling animation like below:

```
- (void)animateFadingOut{

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.00, 1.00);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [self performSelector:@selector(push) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.00, 0.00);
    //set transformation
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

- (void)push
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.00, 1.00);
    // push navigation controloller
    CallViewController *objCallViewController = [[CallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objCallViewController animated:NO];
    [objCallViewController release];
    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
    [[AppDelegate shared] setTabHidden:TRUE];

}
```

But It is not giving me exact animation that default Phone application has

Comment: PLease cuold you attach some code or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I might try if I was trying to create animations.

```
CGRect movementFrame = self.view.frame;
//Make position and size changes as needed to frame
movementFrame.origin.x = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     /*
                       Animation you want to commit go here
                       Apply movementFrame info to the frame
                       of the item we want to animate
                     */

                     //If you wanted a fade
                     self.view.alpha = !self.view.alpha //Simply says I want the reverse.

                     self.view.frame = movementFrame;

                     //Example of what you could do.

                     self.view.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.00, 1.00);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //Things that could happen once the animation is finished
                     [self push];
                 }];
```

This has not been tested for your case. Therefore I  am also not sure if it will help you, but hopefully it will. Good luck to you.

*Edit*

So I reviewed the animation on an iPhone and it appears to me to be a series of animations happening at once.

You have what I presume to be the UIActionSheet animating down.

The top section overlay sliding up its y-axis.

Then you have, which I haven't mastered yet, a split in the back view that animates its x-axis in opposite directions which cause the split.

Finally you have the new view scale up to take frame for the effect.

I can't say 100% this how they have done it, however if I was going to attempt to recreate this, I would likely start here.

Comment: Your code is doing same thing as mine. I am not getting exact animation like default Phone application.Can you tell me which type of animation default Phone app has?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried your steps but still not getting it.

Comment: I'll see if I can recreate it and let you know what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there so after just quickly coming up with an animation I got pretty close it could use some tweaks. 
It took me three views to do a 
`topView, bottomView, and backView.` 
Also took into account the view that you would be loading in. `viewToLoadIn`

`-(void)animation{

```
CGRect topMovementFrame = self.topView.frame; //Set dummy frame to modify 
CGRect bottomViewFrame = self.bottomview.frame;
topMovementFrame.origin.y = 0 - self.topView.frame.size.height; //modify frame's yAxis so that the frame sits above the screen.
bottomViewFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height; //modify frame's yAxis to the it will sit at the bottom of the screen.

[self.viewToLoadIn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     //Animation
                     self.topView.frame = topMovementFrame; //Commit animations
                     self.bottomview.frame = bottomViewFrame;
                     self.backView.alpha = !self.backView.alpha;
                     self.backView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(100, 100);
                     self.viewToLoadIn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 3.0);


                      *MAGIC*
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //Completion
                     //Clean up your views that you are done with here.
                 }];
```

}`

So then When they pressed the button I had setup this animation would happen.

Also at first I thought that the setup might contain a `UIActionStyleSheet`. which it still might but this is a pretty handy built in functionality. But the fact that you can interact with the screen lead me to think a custom view. It would be easier in my opinion.

I hope this helps you even if it just a little bit. 
Take care ^^